# PostgreSQL, select best match from columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table with the following structure in PostgreSQL:

```
table: phonenumbers

columns: user, cc, number_start, number_stop
```

`user` is my USER id, `cc`is country code, `sn_start` is number range first number and `sn_stop` is number range final number.

The table `phonenumbers` can contain multiple number ranges within same country code, and in certain cases there's no number ranges at all.

So first I should fine highest/best match for `cc` and then highest/best match for `number_start` looping until `number_stop`.

How can I select the best match for a given number, ex. `1802569984`?

Example data in table could be:

```
user, cc, number_start, number_stop

1, 44, null, null
3, 1, null, null
3, 1, 800000000, 900000000
4, 1, 802000000, 803000000
```

In this case `user` with ID `4`should be selected, as that is the best match.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: of course, sorry. done :)

Comment: Could you explain why id `4` is best match for `1802569984`? Is it **Step 1:** Cut `1` from `1802569984` then get cc code `1` match, then cut `18` from `1802569984` and get no cc code match (`44` not match, if we have cc `18` then it should be compare next step), then cut `180` from `1802569984`, then cut to `180256998` from `1802569984` to compare CC. After that go to **Step 2:** Cut the remaining after cut `1`, `18`, `180`, .... and then compare to `number_start`, `number_stop`?

Comment: First I need to find the best match for `cc`, in my example I only have two different `cc` which is `44` and `1`. Best match is `1`. Then the remaining numbers in number is `802569984`. This is best match for the range `802000000 - 803000000` which is on user `4`, because it's more precise than range `800000000 - 900000000`.

Comment: You should have a general view of this.  You should assume your table have thousand of records with no exact match, and assume that we have 195 countries, then you must cut your input 3 times: cut 1, cut 2, cut 3 left character of your input in step 1, then cut the remaining and then compare to your columns. That is what you need to do in your query/ store procedure.

Comment: **1.** Do `CC` column will have exact match and `number_start`, `number_stop` is range match? **2.** What is logic for `highest/best match`? If we have input `1800` and 3 rows `1, 700, 900`, `1, 750, 100000`, `1, 10, 850` then which row will be selected?

Comment: `CC` will have exact match, but in the sense that there could be `1` and `180` and then `180` would be the best match for `1802569984`. I just manually went through my entire dataset, and the ranges do not overlap - luckely. They can be `null` so with example `1, null, null` and `1, 10, 850` the last would be most precise.

Comment: I'm thinking of another solution, which would be to generate individual records for each item in the range - would that be easier, better?

Comment: Ex. something like a `view` with `generate_series('020000', '059999')`, but my issue is then I have to store it as `text` because of the possibility of leading zeroes. And then `generate_series` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select e.*
from example e
where (e.number_start is null or 
       e.cc || e.number_start <= '1802569984'
      ) and
      (e.number_end is null or
       '1802569984' <= e.cc || e.numer_end
      )
order by e.cc desc,
         e.number_start desc nulls last,
         e.number_last asc nulls last
limit 1;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to respect that cc could be a prefix. So if number_start is null, it simply select all cc's with number_start null.

Comment: @AlfredBalle . . . I was missing the `limit`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more simple approach, would this work?

```
SELECT p.*
FROM phonenumbers p
WHERE '1802569984' BETWEEN p.cc || p.number_start AND p.cc || p.number_stop
OR ('1802569984' LIKE (p.cc || '%') AND p.number_start IS NULL)
ORDER BY p.cc || p.number_start DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 1;
```